# Trying to combine all excel files within a certain folder with Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to combine all excel files within a certain folder with Power Query. However, I am getting the following error "Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] The key didn't match any rows in the table.. ".

I know that I am getting this error because all of my tab names are different in every file. However, there are more than 500 files and I don't want to change the tab name for all of these. I know for a fact this is the issue, because I changed the tab names for three of the excel files to be the same, and the Power Query is pulling those in. I believe there is only one tab in each file, therefore, I was curious if I could teach the Power Query to grab the tab, regardless of the tab name, so it can be combined.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to use arrow to upvote if you think this answer would help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will combine every tab of every excel files in a directory using powerquery.

Paste it into home ... advanced editor ...

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the sheet by number rather than name. Example at [Microsoft forums](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Referencing-an-Excel-Sheet-Without-Using-Name/m-p/495473#M231002)

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(myPath&myFile),null,true),
#"April 18 Support _Sheet" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Kind] = "Sheet"){0}[Data],
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first, you should answer this question:
Do you want to append all Excel files together?
Or do you want to left-join tables together?

you do it this way:

```
Data > Get&Transform Data > Get Data from file > Excel or CSV
```

in terms of combining, all headers(first raws) should same, but column counts can be different.
But in combining mode, you should load all tables at the first, and try to merge them one by one in ***Power-Query***.

all these steps are saved in the power-query log, and you can use this automated Excel to merge your files every other time.

You can use *`VBA`* too, but it's totally different, you should write `*VBA*` code, but with power-query, you can do it easily just with some clicks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75mxO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yewYC.png)